# Yarn error: Couldn't connect to endpoint URL

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yarnpkg

I have created a sample react web app with package.json have this line
"deploy": "aws s3 sync build/ s3://[mybucketname] --acl public-read",

When I run the yarn build && yarn deploy, the build is successful but deployment gives the error like below:

$ aws s3 sync build/ s3://[mybucketname] --acl public-read
fatal error: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://mybucketname.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=&encoding-type=url"
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

If you see carefully: the actual URL for my bucket is 
http://[mybucketname].s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
whereas yarn is trying to deploy to 
https://[mybucketname].s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

Just to elaborate: there is no https and there is a region in the actual URL of the S3 bucket.

Can anyone help how to solve this problem?

I tried with s3-website://[mybucketname] with no avail

package.json

"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
     "deploy": "aws s3 sync build/ s3://[mybucketname] --acl public-read",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

somehow the yarn deploy should take only http://[mybucketname].s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"

Comment: Are you sure it's a Yarn problem and not AWS CLI?

Comment: Do you have access to S3 bucket? Seems like an AWS access issue instead of Yarn.

Comment: As a first step I would suggest checking if ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials are set correctly. Then look into your IAM to see if you have access to specified bucket. If so, check if there is everything ok with your connectivity (maybe firewall is blocking it). If this is still ok, have you run this command without yarn? Is the result the same?

Comment: @VaradChemburkar : Yes, I ofcourse have access to my bucket. Yarn is formulating a different URl from it's settings which is not matching with the actual bucket URl. I need to solve that problem.I don't know how to reconfigure yarn problem.

Comment: @AnDrOiD: Yes, it has to be Yarn problem because As I said earlier, yarn is trying to connect to url that is formed out of its configuration when it builds and reads the s3 url from package.json

Comment: @necromos: I am running yarn build && yarn deploy. How do i yarn command without yarn?

Comment: @Chimp run `yarn build` and after that type in terminal aws-cli command by hand

Comment: @Chimp `yarn build && aws s3 sync build/ s3://[mybucketname] --acl public-read`. Does this work?

Comment: @VaradChemburkar: Let me try that